# got mysql error when during creating trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

hi iam new to mysql trigger .. this is my first trigger.. i m trying to run but got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE x INT; SET x = new.product_price - old.product_price;
>   INSERT into' at line 9

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER product_update

BEFORE update ON w3xab_virtuemart_product_prices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF (new.product_price <> old.product_price)
THEN 

    DECLARE x decimal(10,2) default 0;
    SET x = new.product_price - old.product_price;
    INSERT into product_price_log(virtuemart_product_id, old_product_price, new_product_price, product_price_update, price_update_date)
    VALUES (new.virtuemart_product_id, old.product_price, new.product_price, new.x, curtime());


END IF;
END$$

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

So move DECLARE after BEGIN.

Comment: Jack iam using insert into product_price_log ..working fine...but when i use  update product_price_log 
set virtuemart_product_id = new.virtuemart_product_id, 
set old_product_price = old.product_price,
set new_product_price = new.product_price,
set product_price_update = x,
set price_update_date = CURDATE();  it will give this ...#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set old_product_price = old.product_price,
    set new_product_price = new.product' at line 11 .....  hope u dont mind

Comment: Use only one `SET`, like - `update product_price_log set virtuemart_product_id = new.virtuemart_product_id, old_product_price = old.product_price,  new_product_price = new.product_price, product_price_update = x,  price_update_date = CURDATE();`