# Can we declare a variable after creating table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a new stored procedure that can auto generate table and it will check the other table and insert the data to the new table. The problem is I get an error .

I already try to add semicolon after creating table and try also remove it, it not working:

```
BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE TEST
      (
      ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      TEST NAME VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 

      UNIQUE(ID),
      PRIMARY KEY (ID)

      );

       <I HAVE ERROR HERE>

        DECLARE vID,vNAME,vADD VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT NAME,ADD FROM OLD_TABLE  

   .......

END$$
```

I expect that the run will compile successfully but it tell me have 1 error

Comment: what exactly was the error message? Also note that `ID`, being a primary key means it is a unique key as well. So remove the `UNIQUE(ID)`. To insert data into the new table,  [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Did you remember the `DELIMITER $$` statement at the beginning?

Comment: yup i remember the delimeter this just a snippet that where my error occured

Comment: it just say that "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE vID,vNAME,vADD VARCHAR(255) 'at line 21
"

Comment: No, [you cannot declare a variable *after*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16093254) you created a table (or did anything else).

Comment: so if case like this what i need to do because i need to create the table first n then insert it ..can u give a suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you read solar flares comment. And you might tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ouhh sory i didn't notice that let me try